# File Directory Redirection with appended text

Tags: batch-file

I have a directory of SQL Backup files that I need to generate a file that I can use to restore these to the SQL database. I can not just create a batch file and use the basic Dir /b pathToFiles > fileList.txt CMD. I need to append text before and after the file name. Please see example below

**Directory Listing of Files**

File-20211207-90121.bak
File-20211207-100456.trn
File-20211207-101457.trn
File-20211207-102457.trn

**Redirected to a file with this format**

RESTORE DATABASE [dbName] FROM DISK = 'C:\filePath\File-20211207-90121.bak' WITH NORECOVERY, REPLACE
RESTORE LOG [dbName] FROM DISK = 'C:\filePath\File-20211207-100456.trn' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [dbName] FROM DISK = 'C:\filePath\File-20211207-101457.trn' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE LOG [dbName] FROM DISK = 'C:\filePath\File-20211207-102457.trn' WITH NORECOVERY
RESTORE DATABASE [dbName] WITH RECOVERY

Although my example above is including the bak file, I would be happy with a solution that just produces a list just for the trn (Transaction files).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Joey**

Comment: Please do not add a solution to the question, post it as an answer instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is just an example that works as you would need it.

```
@echo off

for /f "usebackq" %%a in (`dir /b *.trn`) do (

    echo what you like write before ^"%%~dpfa^" and after
)
```

Comment: I appreciate your time to answer a solution.  I have updated my post above based on your solution.

Comment: `USEBACKQ` is not needed nor do the quotes need to be escaped. The code will fail if the file names have spaces.

Comment: The working solution that I added to my original post provide the correct output (See Above)

Comment: @Squashman: I had not seen spaces in the example of the question. Now I look better.

Comment: @dmaxime does not matter what you see for input examples. You should always program to accept any input. This is best practice: `for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /a-d /b *.trn') do echo what you like write before "%%~dpfa" and after`

Comment: The easier solution would have been to use a standard for command. `FOR %%G IN (*.trn) do echo what you like write before "%%~fG" and after`

Comment: @Squashman (The easier solution...) I'd agree with you if 'dir' was an external command. In reality my imprecision derives from the fact that I intended to offer an idea and not write the program for him. My habit of using 'usebackq' comes from the fact that it makes the quotes compatible with those of the *nix world and I find it personally comfortable and then as often happens, something to escape always comes. :)